# How to keep only a user-defined quantity of labels?

Tags: label, pine-script

First of all sorry for the likely dumb question but i have problems with the label.delete() function used to keep a limited number of labels on charts and deleting older ones, i used this code as reference: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/concepts/Text_and_shapes.html#deleting-labels
on a function used to create pivots but does not seem to work since it deletes all newer labels created without deleting the older ones, here is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='RSI Pivot', precision=0, max_labels_count=500)
qtyLabelsInput = input.int(20, 'Labels to keep', minval=0)
myRSI = ta.rsi(close, 20)
plot(myRSI)

drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _size, _text, _textcolor) =>
    if (_pivot)
        label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, style=_style, size=_size, text=_text, textcolor=_textcolor)
    if array.size(label.all) > qtyLabelsInput
        label.delete(array.get(label.all, 0))

leftLenH = input.int(title='Pivot High main', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot High main')
rightLenH = input.int(title='/', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot High main')
leftLenL = input.int(title='Pivot Low main', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot Low main')
rightLenL = input.int(title='/', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot Low main')
ph = ta.pivothigh(myRSI, leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(myRSI, leftLenL, rightLenL)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------MAIN label
drawLabel(rightLenH, ph, label.style_none, size.tiny , "T", color.red)
drawLabel(rightLenL, pl, label.style_none, size.tiny, "B", color.green)
```

EDIT CODE 2:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='CMF Pivot', precision=0, max_labels_count=500)
qtyLabelsInput = input.int(20, 'Labels to keep', minval=0)
myRSI = ta.rsi(close, 20)
plot(myRSI, "RSI")


drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _size, _text, _textcolor, _y) =>
//          x        y                                      y(2)=na?       plot location     
    var label[] label_array = array.new_label(qtyLabelsInput)
    if (_pivot)
        array.unshift(label_array, label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, style=_style, size=_size, text=_text, textcolor=_textcolor, y=_y))
        label.delete(array.pop(label_array))

//cmf code
var cumVol = 0.
cumVol += nz(volume)
if barstate.islast and cumVol == 0
    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
ad = close==high and close==low or high==low ? 0 : ((2*close-low-high)/(high-low))*volume
cmf = math.sum(ad, length) / math.sum(volume, length)
//

leftLenH = input.int(title='Pivot High main', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot High main')
rightLenH = input.int(title='/', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot High main')
leftLenL = input.int(title='Pivot Low main', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot Low main')
rightLenL = input.int(title='/', defval=2, minval=1, inline='Pivot Low main')
ph = ta.pivothigh(cmf, leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(cmf, leftLenL, rightLenL)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------MAIN label
//drawLabel(rightLenH, ph, label.style_none, size.tiny , "T", color.red, myRSI)
//drawLabel(rightLenL, pl, label.style_none, size.tiny, "B", color.green, myRSI)

plotchar(ph, location=location.top, size = size.tiny, text = "H", textcolor = color.red, show_last=15, color=#000000)
plotchar(pl, location=location.bottom, size = size.tiny, text = "L", textcolor = color.green, show_last=15, color=#000000)
```

Comment: I also have to say that i'd gladly use the show_last function that works perfectly with the simpler plot f. but there is no way to use it with the plotshape, plotchar or plotarrow function that also allow the use of text on the plotted label which i require and not possible with the plain plot f.

Comment: EDIT:  you can do that see code 2 above

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your labels of a fixed number by using a var label array. When your condition is met and you are adding a new label to the array, you also remove and delete the last label in order to keep a fixed number of labels.

```
drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _size, _text, _textcolor) =>
    var label[] label_array = array.new_label(qtyLabelsInput)
    if (_pivot)
        array.unshift(label_array, label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, style=_style, size=_size, text=_text, textcolor=_textcolor))
        label.delete(array.pop(label_array))
```

Comment: Thank you Rumpypumpydumpy, sorry to bother again but i have issues setting up a custom plotting for the label on the y axis with the y argument on the label.new function is there some kind of incompatibility with arrays that i am missing or is simply the result of my incompetence?

Comment: There's no incompatibility as far as I'm aware. I can't really tell you any more without seeing what you're doing though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, thanks again for your help

```
drawLabel(_pivot, _y, _style, _size, _text, _textcolor) =>
    var label[] label_array = array.new_label(qtyLabelsInput)
    if _pivot
        array.unshift(label_array, label.new(bar_index[_pivot], y=_y, style=_style, size=_size, text=_text, textcolor=_textcolor))
        label.delete(array.pop(label_array))
```